# Record of maps with compositional lookups and updates?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, ghc-generics

Some pseudocode:

```
data A = A
data B = B
data C = C
data D = D
data E = E
data F = F
data G = G

data A1 = A1 A B C
data A2 = A2 A
data A3 = A3 B C D
data A4 = A4 D E F
data A5 = A5 A1 A4 G

data Foo k = Foo
    {
        a1s :: Map.Map k A1,
        a2s :: Map.Map k A2,
        a3s :: Map.Map k A3,
        a4s :: Map.Map k A4,
        a5s :: Map.Map k A5,
--and my attempted solution would use
        -- e.g. [(A1, [(A, Unit), (B, Unit), (C, Unit)]), (A5, [(A1, Composite), (A4, Composite), (G, Unit) ]) ]
        componentMap :: Map.Map Type (Set Type),

        -- e.g. [(A, [A1, A2]), (A1, [A5, A1]) ]
        compositeMap :: Map.Map Type (Set Type)
    }
```

I'd like to construct some kind of data structure that looks like this. From here, I'd like to:

- `lookup :: Foo k -> k -> Either FailureReason v`  individual values; if we assume that we have populated maps, I'd like `lookup foo a1 :: A1`, but also transitive instances such as `lookup foo a1 :: B` or `lookup foo a5 :: A1` (since this is shorthand for `getA1fromA5 $ lookup foo a5`) and `lookup foo a5 :: B`. I'm considering `FailureReason = WrongType | NotPresent` but this is probably excessive.
- traversals over types such as an (indexed) traversal over `(k, D)` which should hit everything in `A3, A4, A5`

This could be implemented as a recursive search over `componentMap` and `compositeMap`..so long as they were populated by hand.

Since the above seem very much recursive, I feel this has a `GHC.Generics` solution. Possibly a `lens/optics + generic-lens/generic-optics` one?

Or is my solution one that doesn't need `generics` and its ilk, and is instead just writing some traversals and lenses to index into my structure?

The question then becomes: is this functionality already existing in some library? If not, is `Generics` the tool I'm looking for to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't actually want multiple maps here -- that is, a given key should correspond to exactly one value, not an `A1` value from the `a1s` map and another `A2` value from from the `a2s` map, etc.

Also, you haven't said what you want to do if there are multiple matches of a particular type within in a single value, for example if you have values of type:

```
data A6 = A6 A3 A4
```

and try to retrieve or traverse terms of type `D`.  Below, I assume you want to retrieve and/or traverse only the "first" one encountered (e.g., the `D` in `A3` only, ignoring the one in `A4`).

Anyway, you can do this with `Data` generics and some helpers from `lens`'s `Data.Data.Lens`.

No special data type is needed.  A plain `Map` is sufficient, with a sum type to represent the collection of values you want to store:

```
data Dat = D_A1 A1 | D_A2 A2 | D_A3 A3 | D_A4 A4 | D_A5 A5 deriving (Data)
type Foo k dat = Map k dat
```

To look up a (possibly deeply nested) value by key, we can use the `biplate` traversal from `lens`:

```
lookupFoo :: (Ord k, Typeable v, Data dat) => k -> Foo k dat -> Maybe v
lookupFoo k foo = do
  dat <- Map.lookup k foo
  firstOf biplate dat
```

Here, `biplate` recursively traverses all the subterms of type `v` in the term `dat`.  The `firstOf` query returns the first matching term or `Nothing` if no terms are found.  (The `do` block is running in the `Maybe` monad.)

To perform an indexed traversal, we can also use `biplate`, modified using `taking 1` to traverse only the first match:

```
itraverseFoo :: (Applicative f, Typeable v, Data dat) => (k -> v -> f v) -> Foo k dat -> f (Foo k dat)
itraverseFoo f foo = Map.traverseWithKey f' foo
  where f' k dat = taking 1 biplate (f k) dat
```

The full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Data
import Data.Data.Lens
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data Dat = D_A1 A1 | D_A2 A2 | D_A3 A3 | D_A4 A4 | D_A5 A5 | D_A6 A6 deriving (Data)
type Foo k dat = Map k dat

lookupFoo :: (Ord k, Typeable v, Data dat) => k -> Foo k dat -> Maybe v
lookupFoo k foo = do
  dat <- Map.lookup k foo
  firstOf biplate dat

itraverseFoo :: (Applicative f, Typeable v, Data dat) => (k -> v -> f v) -> Foo k dat -> f (Foo k dat)
itraverseFoo f foo = Map.traverseWithKey f' foo
  where f' k dat = taking 1 biplate (f k) dat

data A = A deriving (Data, Show)
data B = B deriving (Data, Show)
data C = C deriving (Data, Show)
data D = D deriving (Data, Show)
data E = E deriving (Data, Show)
data F = F deriving (Data, Show)
data G = G deriving (Data, Show)

data A1 = A1 A B C deriving (Data, Show)
data A2 = A2 A deriving (Data, Show)
data A3 = A3 B C D deriving (Data, Show)
data A4 = A4 D E F deriving (Data, Show)
data A5 = A5 A1 A4 G deriving (Data, Show)
data A6 = A6 A3 A4 deriving (Data, Show)

foo :: Foo String Dat
foo = Map.fromList [ ("a1", D_A1 (A1 A B C))
                   , ("a3", D_A3 (A3 B C D))
                   , ("a4", D_A4 (A4 D E F))
                   , ("a5", D_A5 (A5 (A1 A B C) (A4 D E F) G))
                   , ("a6", D_A6 (A6 (A3 B C D) (A4 D E F)))
                   ]

find :: forall a k. k -> a -> Writer [k] a
find k a = tell [k] >> pure a

main = do
  print $ (lookupFoo "a1" foo :: Maybe A1)
  print $ (lookupFoo "a1" foo :: Maybe B)
  print $ (lookupFoo "a5" foo :: Maybe A1)
  print $ (lookupFoo "a5" foo :: Maybe B)
  print $ execWriter (itraverseFoo (find @D) foo)
```